# MySQL Query does not return current day's records

Tags: mysql, sql, date

The following query does not return records for the ending date (20th April). I read somewhere that is it because time is not taken into account with the date passed into the query. But after researching various solutions, I can't seem to figure it out for MySQL.

```
select * from listings
where created_date >= '2020-04-18' 
and created_date <= '2020-04-20'
```

created_date is a datetime field.

Note, I can't use "between" in this situation.

Comment: share your db schema

Comment: use date function to convert created_date https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

Comment: Please share the table structure, sample input data and the expected output for this data, such that others can reproduce your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `created_date` is a `DATETIME`, it will have a time part which is probably not zero. When you compare it to a date with no time part, the time part of that date is set to 0, and so the test fails. You need to preferably use:

```
 created_date < '2020-04-21'
```

or you can include the time part, but this will slow comparisons:

```
 created_date <= '2020-04-20 23:59:59'
```

or alternatively, take the `DATE` part and compare that, but that has the downside of preventing use of an index on `created_date`:

```
DATE(created_date) <= '2020-04-20'
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/145468)

Answer (score 0):

The best logic is:

```
where created_date >= '2020-04-18' and
      created_date < '2020-04-21'
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
where created_date >= '2020-04-18' and
      created_date < date('2020-04-20') + interval 1 day
```

These are index- and optimizer- safe because there are no functions on the column.  They also work regardless of whether or not there is a time component.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: **why** is this the best logic?

Comment: @NicoHaase . . . Because it works for dates with and without a time component.  It allows the use of indexes.  And it doesn't confuse the optimizer.  I thought the answer addressed that.